# How to avoid try-catch in android studio when i'm sure ther won't be null?

Tags: android

I have some code.

```java
String id = new UserJSONModel( new JSONObject(SharedPreferenceManager.read(
SharedPreferenceManager.AUTH, "")).getJSONObject("user")).getId();
```

I'm preety sure that AUTH strored in Shared Preferences isn't null becouse i store it after retrieving token from it and remove it on logout. I don't want to do try-catch on entire block of code so i put "if null" but android studio still wants me to use try-catch.

```
String auth = SharedPreferenceManager.read(SharedPreferenceManager.AUTH, "");
       if (auth == null) {

       } else {
          UserJSONModel user = new JSONObject(auth);
          String id = eser.getId();
       }
```

Comment: It's a safety precaution. You don't want user to crash if 1 in a millionth time you receive null ID?

Comment: Try suppressing the warning

Comment: Avoiding try catch especially for Shared preferences is risky. For eg. : Going to 'App Info' settings and clicking 'Clear Storage' button will clear the app database and Shared preferences. You can't guarantee its always not null. The user might use storage clear utility software which might clear it all.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio lets warn and force you to use `try/catch` when there is a method which could throw an `exception` , so instead of trying to avoid `try/catch` , think that one of your user may somehow  face `null` and instead of letting you app crashes you better handle it for a better user experience

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. `throws` always require `try/catch` block. It's Java's rule.

Explanation on why it needs it.
JSONObject will throw a `JSONException` if `auth` is not the right json format. Null check will not cut it because Android Studio has no way of knowing if the format of `auth` is valid. That's why it wants you to surround `new JSONObject` with a try/catch block.

The try/catch block is from `JSONObject`'s `contructor`. If you don't want to use try/catch block then you can use a different way to parse/stringify your json. Like Gson library. Or use Kotlin, `throws` doesn't require `try/catch` in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the original poster, I find it frustrating and will result in not throwing the exception at all when you implement error handling in your own code.

Most answers propose adding the try/catch block, but actually the rule of thumb in programming in general is: "only catch exceptions that you can handle". Mandating a try catch around any method that may throw an exception would mean you need to wrap most of your code lines, as if you were testing for success in an if block. It just defeats the purpose of the exception idea.

Exceptions can be handled at a higher level, the concept of top-level exception handlers represents that.

When implementing your own code, throw a RuntimeException instead of an Exception. RuntimeExceptions don't need wrapping.
In your case, it doesn't work as you are using someone else's code.